# How to change stdio of a given process (i.e. not current process)?

Tags: go, ps, dup2

Here is a way to change stdio of a given process by external tools such as `gdb`:

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/redirect-output-of-running-process

My question is, how can I do this programatically?  I am using Go, bug example in C is also OK.

**EDIT**

My go program starts a `bash` instance inside a `pty`. User can run **any** command inside the pty.  After the user types `exit` inside the terminal, bash will quit, but any background process will prevent the session from close cleanly.

I want to modify the stdio of any (grand) child processes of the bash, so that in its process' `/proc/*/fd/`, its `0`, `1`, `2` fd points to `/dev/null`, just like the `nohup` program do when it starts a program.

Obvioulsy it is impossible to let user **always** use `nohup` when run a command. So I want to do the clean up inside my go service program, so that the terminal does not hang.

Answer (score 0):

so, I am making some assumptions to answer your questions which are as follows:

1. the process you are taking about is a linux process.
2. the program/process is perhaps being triggered using a go program.

   OR
3. if not, you are rather proposing writing a demon of sorts in go that can intercept processed that are actively outputting to console in attempt to redirect it while its running.

if **process is being triggered using a go program:**

- Why don't you redirect output while triggering the process?

if **you want Go program to intercept a running process:**

- checkout https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec
- you can use it to trigger shell commands.
- you can use shell commands to invoke tools mentioned in the article you linked.

Comment: The go program exec a `bash` instance, and the bash instance exec a background process, and then the bash exits, I want to change the stdio of the background process.

Comment: so why can't you mention the redirect destination in the instruction which bash instance uses to exec a background proccess ?

Comment: The bash instance is started by go program in a `pty`, and the background instance is started **manually** in the interactive session.  i.e. I want to disconnect `stdio` of any (grand) child process of the bash, after it exits.